# Use external module in internal component

Tags: angular

I Used the a owl-carousel module in my angular 7 project.
How to used this module from internal component?

In my app.module.ts file :

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { OwlModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';

imports: [
   ...
   OwlModule, 
   SharedModule ]
```

In my shared.module.ts File:

```
import { BannerCarouselComponent } from './components/carousels/banner-carousel/banner-carousel.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [BannerCarouselComponent] ...
```

In my banner-carousel.component.html File:

```
<owl-carousel  [options]="bannerCarouselOptions" [items]="images" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding']" >
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of mySlideImages;let i = index">
     <div>
       <img src={{image}}/>
     </div>
    </div>

   </owl-carousel>
```

Please Tell me what do i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you already imported the sharedModule in your appModule. The only thing you need to do is to use selector of your `BannerCarouselComponent` in the html page.

If your intend is to use this SharedModule accross all the application, then you also need to add `SharedModule` into your exports of your AppModule as well.